# Show apps pictures in Android Gallery with Android Nougat

Tags: java, android, android-camera

How do you grant the proper permissions and set the correct path in order to display an apps photos in the native Android Gallery app with FileProvider in Android Nougat?

Below is the current code. It will save photos locally, but the photos aren't displayed in the Android Gallery app.

**CameraActivity.java**

```
public class CameraPreviewActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements CameraPreviewFragment.Callback {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        showCamera();
    }

    public void showCameraPreviewFile() {
        _photoFileUri = generateTimestampPhotoUri();
        if (_photoFileUri != null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, _photoFileUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PHOTO_INTENT_WITH_FILENAME);
        }
    }

    File getPhotoDirectory() {
        File outputDir = null;
        String externalStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (externalStorageState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            File picturesDir =
                    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            outputDir = new File(picturesDir, getString(R.string.app_name));
            if (!outputDir.exists()) {
                if (!outputDir.mkdirs()) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "outputDir.mkdirs: error");
                    outputDir = null;
                }
            }
        }
        return outputDir;
    }

    Uri generateTimestampPhotoUri() {
        Uri photoUri = null;
        File outputDir = getPhotoDirectory();
        File photoFile = null;

        if (outputDir != null) {
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            String photoFileName = "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
            photoFile = new File(outputDir, photoFileName);
        }

        if (photoFile != null) {
            photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                    this,
                    this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider",
                    photoFile
            );
        }

        return photoUri;
    }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
```

**xml/provider_paths.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="MyApp" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no single "native Android Gallery app". There are ~2 billion Android devices, spread across thousands of device models. There are hundreds of pre-installed "gallery" apps on those devices, as device manufacturers routinely ship their own. There are also "gallery" apps available for users to install from app markets.

Their behaviors will vary. Many will use `MediaStore` to find the photos to view. You are not doing anything to arrange to have your image be indexed by the `MediaStore`. Use `MediaScannerConnection` and its `scanFile()` method, in `onActivityResult()`, to have the `MediaStore` update its catalog to include your image.

Comment: I was able to call it, and the `onScanCompletedListener` callback succeeded. I don't however yet see the image in the Gallery.  Does it take some time to sync? Also, this is my file path: `content://com.myapp.myapp.provider/Myapp/Pictures/Myapp/IMG_20161129_073601.jpg` I'm assuming this is a valid file path to be discovered by the Gallery app?  Thank you so much for your help. There's so much to learn in Android, it feels easy to get stuck.

Comment: @AaronLelevier: "this is my file path" -- that is not a file path. "I'm assuming this is a valid file path to be discovered by the Gallery app?" -- no. That is a `Uri` pointing to your `FileProvider`. Your file path is in the `photoFile` object. You need to hold onto this value, including across configuration changes (e.g., use `onSaveInstanceState()`). And you need to use the file path from `photoFile` in your `scanFile()` call.